# Equivalent (functionality) of ObjPtr from VB6 in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb6

Does any one know if C# has an equivalent of ObjPtr from VB6, or equivalent functionality (see more info below)?  Here are a couple of links to info on ObjPtr [devx](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18398) , [thevbzone](http://www.thevbzone.com/secrets.htm).

Basically I have a third party treeview that I need to walk thru to get specific nodes but the only (relevant) info the nodes have is name ... but the node names don't need to be unique.  So I need to get a unique value for each node as I walk thru it the first time so when I walk thru it again I know which is which.  In the old school VB6 days I would use ObjPtr.

Comment: From your description, I don’t understand why you used `ObjPtr`. That’s a real low-level hacky thing to do, and it sounds like in your case simple object equality testing via `Is` should suffice. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Well ObjPtr might not have been the best choice but I had taken over a large code base and it was used through out the code...and it worked.  In this case, again the is an older code base again..."IS" might work if I update the code more, right now the initial walk thru of the treeview only stores the name in an array to reference back to so I don't have the object itself to compare to.

Comment: Why not store an object reference? No disadvantages compared to storing the name. Just as fast and uses same amount of memory.

Comment: @MarkJ: to answer your question: when you want to store a 'dumb pointer' without affecting the COM reference count e.g. where a child keeps a reference to its parent while avoiding a circular reference. The CopyMemory API can be use to 'rehydrate' dumb pointer to a 'real' reference when required.

Comment: @onedaywhen - good explanation of VB6 usage of ObjPtr but the question is about what to do in **C#**, when the circular reference problem does not apply. I still think FKCoder should just store an object reference in C# to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The closest direct equivalent I can think of would be to use a GCHandle to get an IntPtr for your object reference.

You would need to allocate a GCHandle for your object (GCHandle.Alloc), then use [GCHandle.ToIntPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.tointptr.aspx) to convert to an IntPtr.  The linked documentation shows the process.

Comment: I think you're correct - this is the closest equivalent to ObjPtr - but I don't think FKCoder should be using this atom bomb to crack his particular walnut

Comment: I agree - but I was trying to answer the question directly, anyways.

Answer (score 2):

If they're objects, why not just store the object references directly? These will be unique.

You can use `Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)` to determine if a reference you have stored is referring to the same object you just retrieved from the tree.

Answer (score 1):

If the treenode has FullPath property, you can use it to uniquely identify a node in the treeview (Winforms Treeview  has the [FullPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.fullpath.aspx) property). This won't be unique if 2 siblings have same text in it.

OR

You could use [Handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.handle.aspx) property of the TreeNode.

Comment: Question does say it's a third-party treeview, so it may not have the standard properties

Answer (score -2):

[GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) should work well for testing unique values unless the third-party has overriden the Object implementation with something that doesn't make sense in your scenario.

I would assume that nodes in the tree would define equality/hashcode by more than just the value string, but you would need to check.

Comment: -1. "The default implementation of the GetHashCode method does **not** guarantee unique return values for different objects." It is intended for *hashing* not to provide unique identifiers. From MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx

Comment: -1 Hashcode is not intended and for this and should never be used that way.