# Name 'ObjPtr' is not declared. VB6 to VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb6

I am usually a C# programmer but I have been tasked with updating ancient VB6 to .NET to work with an add-in program we have here.  I am running into the error in the title.   I have tracked down a code snippet to handle VarPtr ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019214/name-varptr-is-not-declared-in-old-vb-code)) and from what I read StrPtr can just be removed and it *should* be fine.  No matter how hard I try I can't find anything to use with ObjPtr.

Two things, correct me if the VarPtr or StrPrt points are wrong as .NET is not my first language and secondly, HELP!

Here is the code for one of the errors:

```
 Private Function PrivatePtr(ByVal MyPtr As Integer, ByRef Obj As Object) As Integer
    ' returns corresponding pointer a private member of an
    ' object of this type (type of Me), given a pointer to
    ' Me's corresponding private variable

    If (objptr(Obj) <> 0) Then

        PrivatePtr = UnsignedAdd(ObjPtr(Obj), UnsignedSubtract(MyPtr, ObjPtr(Me)))
    End If
End Function ' PrivatePtr
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do `UnsignedAdd` and `UnsignedSubtract` do? Do you actually need to use pointers to achieve your underlying goal?

Comment: See if the answers to this question help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374664/equivalent-functionality-of-objptr-from-vb6-in-c

Comment: @Blackwood That _could be_ a duplicate but the answers are fairly general - I'm not sure it's terribly useful.

Comment: @xxbbcc I agree, I wouldn't suggest that this is a duplicate, I just thought the OP may learn a little from it.

Comment: In general, anything being done in VB6 with ObjPtr shouldn't be ported "directly" to .Net unless you're dealing with some kind of lower level third-party DLL that requires pointers; in which case you'd be using some kind of GCHandle.  Otherwise you should be looking at how to achieve the same functionality by **re-writing** the code to do the same thing as if you'd written it from scratch in .Net to begin with.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Pretty much what I was going to write, but a lot clearer than mine.... John, you have the opportunity to rewrite things for the better. Don't just do a 1:1 port. You'll end up handicapping the application right off the bat. Unless you are on a serious deadline and don't think you have the time to make anything better then so be it, but this is your chance to fix and clean-up sections of code that probably made people bash their heads on their keyboards.

Comment: As an example of a bad (possibly crippling) porting effort: pointers are `Integer` only when running 32-bit code. On 64-bit platforms, you need 64-bit values to store pointer values. `IntPtr` internally handles this but if you use `Integer`, you'll have problems later on.

Comment: Thanks all.  I will review that link @Blackwood

Comment: @TyCobb, my actual end goal is to rewrite it in C#, but I am under a tight TIGHT deadline so the 1:1 port made the most short term sense.  I didn't write the OC so I have to take the time to tear it down to rebuild it, which I don't truly have the overhead for.